# Is it possible to save javascript from a .bat?

Tags: javascript, batch-file

So I'm trying to basically create a .bat with .js code inside of it and save the .js as a .js file and run the .js from the bat file. Is it possible?

```
echo hello > file-name.js
echo world >> file-name.js
(
  echo Line 1
  echo Line 2
  echo Line 3
) > file-name.js
```

I think because my .js code has lots of brackets/code in, the .bat reads it as batch and won't do it.

Please help!

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/386424). What is your end goal? Why are you trying to do this? (Why do you want to run a .bat file that creates and runs a .js file? What does the .js file end up doing / what purpose does it serve?)

Comment: Give example(s) of problematic lines and we can explain how to escape each.  But the basics is that `%` has to be replaced with `%%`, and there are several special characters that require a caret, such as `!`, and `)` need to be `^!` and `^)`.  See this page for partial details: https://riptutorial.com/batch-file/example/32077/escape-using-caret---

Comment: Once your javascript is correctly formatted, it can be run with `cscript.exe //nologo "path\filename.js"`

Comment: I'm trying to run a node js file but I need the bat to generate it -- not sure if it's possible to include js code in a bat without it breaking the bat.

Comment: @SarahSmith, I'm not sure if there is any problem that cannot be overcome.  Yes, batch files have issues sending text to a file, but the real issue is figuring out the right characters to send out.  For example, I've ran into situation where it took `%%%%%%%%` just to output something like `%%`.  But sometimes, the better answer might be to first save the line to a variable and then echo out the variable.  An alternative might be to use PowerShell, which by the way, can be both inside the batch file and at the same time ran from the batch file.  How large/complex is the js?

Comment: The js is pretty large it's 20kb so I'm losing hope lol

Comment: Like Darin said, all you have to do is escape some characters and everything will work correctly. I see this get done all the time.

Comment: You have a 20kb file you're trying to embed in a batch file?  Why?  Why can't it be it's own file?  What on earth do you possibly hope to achieve by making this hard?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Save this script in a file with the CMD extension, for example MultiLargeJSOut.CMD.  When ran, it created 3 files, each with every special character available on the keyboard.

This script:

1. Is divided into two parts.  The first part is ordinary Batch language that is wrapped in what PowerShell sees as a multiline comment.  The batch part calls PowerShell, which in tern loads the script in memory and executes it as PowerShell.  PowerShell, seeing the multiline comment wrapped around the Batch code, will skip it and execute only the PowerShell in the second half of the file.
2. The PowerShell half is ran twice, the first time it creates the first two files, and the second time it creates the third file.
3. With each call to the PowerShell half, parameters are passed telling it what to do.  The first call it passes F1 and F2, the second call passes F3.
4. The parameters are passed in PowerShell to the `switch` statement which uses each parameter/argument to decide which PowerShell function to call.
5. Each PowerShell function creates one of the files using the `Out-File` function with the `-Encoding ASCII` parameter.  If you need special Unicode characters, then you wil want to use a different encoding, such as UTF7, UTF8, or UTF32.  To see all options, look at [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file).
6. Can easily be modified by replacing the text between the `@'` and `'@` with the js code you desire - in theory, even 20K in size.  I am not aware of any reason there would be limit, but the real test will be when you try.
7. Can be reduced to only one function creating one file, or as many functions as you need.  Just adjust the `switch` command and functions as needed.

**NOTE:** The colon in the first line is important.  I believe it is tricking Batch into thinking this line is a label.  So keep it `<# :` and don't reduce it to `<#`.  Also, you should be able to place any text you want after the colon on the first line, and it should act like a comment and be ignored.

```
<# :
@ECHO OFF
    REM Need F0 for PowerShell to load this script in memory.
    SET F0=%~f0
    REM Need CMDScriptRoot in PowerShell to find the folder/directory that the script is located.
    SET CMDScriptRoot=%~dp0
    
    REM Batch code before creating files.
    
    PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Command ".([scriptblock]::Create('.([scriptblock]::Create((get-content -raw $Env:F0))) F1 F2'))"
    
    REM Batch code in the middle of creating files.
    
    PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Command ".([scriptblock]::Create('.([scriptblock]::Create((get-content -raw $Env:F0))) F3'))"
    
    REM Batch code after creating files.
GOTO :EOF
<#~#>
function File1 {
    $FileText = @'
1:~!@#$%^&*()_+
1:Place any text
1:you want
1:saved to
1:a file
1:in these lines
`-=
{}|
[]\
:"
;'
<>?
,./
'@
    # Note: CMDScriptRoot points to the same path where this script is located.
    # $FileText | Out-File -FilePath "$($Env:CMDScriptRoot)\file-name1.js"  -Encoding ASCII
    $FileText | Out-File -FilePath "$($Env:USERPROFILE)\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\file-name1.js" -Encoding ASCII
}

function File2 {
    $FileText = @'
2:~!@#$%^&*()_+
2:Place any text
2:you want
2:saved to
2:a file
2:in these lines
`-=
{}|
[]\
:"
;'
<>?
,./
'@
    # $FileText | Out-File -FilePath "$($Env:CMDScriptRoot)\file-name2.js"  -Encoding ASCII
    $FileText | Out-File -FilePath "$($Env:USERPROFILE)\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\file-name2.js" -Encoding ASCII
}
function File3 {
    $FileText = @'
3:~!@#$%^&*()_+
3:Place any text
3:you want
3:saved to
3:a file
3:in these lines
`-=
{}|
[]\
:"
;'
<>?
,./
'@
    # $FileText | Out-File -FilePath "$($Env:CMDScriptRoot)\file-name3.js"  -Encoding ASCII
    $FileText | Out-File -FilePath "$($Env:USERPROFILE)\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\file-name3.js" -Encoding ASCII
}
switch ($args) {
    'F1' {
        File1
        continue
    }
    'F2' {
        File2
        continue
    }
    'F3' {
        File3
        continue
    }
    default {
        continue
    }
}
```

Comment: You Sir, are a genius. Thank you. Could you add me on Discord? Administrator#0002

Comment: Could you edit the script so it drops the .js in %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup please!

Comment: @SarahSmith, "genius", no.  I spent years working in batch, with some C#, and in spring of 2019 I got caught in a situation where I needed to create the equivalent to a content management system in 3 weeks.  Batch was the only language I had that level of skill and it took 6 weeks, plus months of fixing problems.  Never again!  I have worked hard, and continue to work hard, to learn PowerShell.  What I have given you here is a foundation for getting started in PowerShell.  If you put some work into it, and use the right tools such VSCode, it will serve you well.

Comment: Concerning environmental variables, `$Env:USERPROFILE` in PowerShell is the same as `%USERPROFILE%` in batch.  PowerShell has 2 types of strings.  Those in 'single quotes', and expandable strings in "double quotes".  PowerShell variables start with a $, and will expand in an expandable string, so if $Var has the value 'Yes', then "The answer is $Var" will become "The answer is Yes".  But the expansion can have problems if the variable name is followed by a colon `:`, so I wrap environment variables in expanding strings in `$(`...`)`.  This may not be best practice, still learning.

Comment: Let me know if there are other needed modifications.  Also, in case you don't know this, you can write a batch file in such a way to receive files that are dragged and dropped onto it from Windows explorer.  When the file(s) are dropped onto the batch, the batch starts running and receives the files as %1, %2, etc...  This allows the batch script to process, or do some work with, those files.  And, since batch can run PowerShell, this means the PowerShell can be used to process the files.  This is a functionality that PowerShell does not have, so the hybrid is better than both.

Comment: Darin, thank you for your reply !! You've really helped me. I was wondering if you knew if it was possible to receive notifications in some place like email, or anywhere, any way, via a .bat? So when they open the .bat I get notified. Thank you.

Comment: @SarahSmith, unfortunately, that is an area that is hard to nail down without a lot more info.  And email is not yet a strong point for me.  Your best bet is probably to create a new question here on SO, and include all the relevant details.